# Checkbox formula comparing fields on two objects

Tags: formula, formula-field, checkbox

I want to create a checkbox formula on a child object that checks if a field matches a field on the parent object.

The relationship between the two is lookup.

I've tried

```
Name = Account.minInvoiceNumber__c
```

But I get the error

```
Check Syntax Error: Field Account does not exist. Check spelling.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a standard relationship? I am assuming that no. If not, you should use __r:

```
Name = Account__r.minInvoiceNumber__c
```

Comment: Even if the child object is a standard SObject, if the lookup to `Account` is a custom field (as opposed to a standard relationship field), you'd need to use the `__r` syntax. Still, +1 from me for taking the words out of my mouth (or rather, taking the keys from under my fingers).

Comment: Yes, @DerekF. I would like to say a standard relationship. Like Account and Contacts, for example.